# Why did the armor made for Eragon/Saphira change?

Tags: production-mistakes, eragon

In the 2006 film "Eragon", the resistance fighters called the Varden made armor for protagonist Eragon and his dragon Saphira. He was told that they worked all night to complete the armor in time for the pending battle. The armor shown was heavy plate armor, with Saphira's helm covering her entire face.

Later in the battle, however, both Eragon & Saphira are wearing a much lighter scale armor, with Saphira wearing a completely different helm. No explanation is given, so I'm assuming this was a production error due to a change in the battle scene, with the original armor left in by accident.

**Why did the armor change from heavy plate to scale? Has anyone involved with the production commented on the change?**

*Note: Please note that I am NOT asking about anything related to the source novels - only the film.*